# Laravel merge array where the id's are the same

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

my transformer returns this:

```
{
  "id": "6",
  "first_name": "Marco"
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "first_name": "Michel"
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "first_name": "Marjorie"
},
```

I would like my data like this:

```
{
6: {
    "first_name": "Marco"
  }
},
{
4: {
  "first_name": "Michel",
  "first_name": "Marjorie"
}
},
```

So I need to merge my array together where the id's are the same:

this is the array I send to my transformer:

```
[
0 => array:2 [▼
  "id" => "6"
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "first_name" => "Marco"
  ]
]
1 => array:2 [▼
  "id" => "4"
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "first_name" => "Michel"
  ]
]
2 => array:2 [▼
  "id" => "4"
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "first_name" => "Marjorie"
  ]
]
]
```

this is my transformer:

```
return [
    'id' => $entity->getCompanyId(),
    [
        'first_name' => $entity->getFirstName() ?? '/'
    ]
];
```

I don't think I should change my array how I send it to the transformer nor the transformer I think I should just edit the array that my transformer return.

But I don't know how I can merge an array based on a key value (id in this case)

Comment: what is the `$entity`

Comment: @TsaiKoga thats just my person entity it has an id and a firstName property

Comment: I found the format that you want is wrong, it is impossible to have two keys that named 'first_name' in one dictionary `4: {
  "first_name": "Michel",
  "first_name": "Marjorie"
}`